# Apache web server Segmentation Fault error when connecting to a Postgres Database

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, python-2.7, apache

I have a python flask web app running on an apache server. The flask app is just one function returning a value that I get from the postgres database.

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    import psycopg2
    db_conn_string = ("dbname=" + "xxx"
                        + " user=" + "xxx"
                        + " host=" + "xxx"
                        + " password=" + "xxx")
    db_connection = psycopg2.connect(db_conn_string)
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM XXX")
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

When I run this app I get this on the browser:

[image]

I checked the logs under `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and the error is:

```
[Fri Jan 24 10:34:34.676561 2020] [core:notice] [pid 15644:tid 139639322680256] AH00051: child pid 15972 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

Interestingly, when I change the return statement to just return a hello world it runs just fine and I don't see any error. So my hypothesis is that the error is due to the apache web app trying to connect to the postgres database. I checked the credentials of the database and there is nothing wrong there. I don't know how to fix this.

**EDIT**: a test python program with the same code works and I am able to retrieve data.

Comment: Waht result do you get when you run your function in a Python test program?

Comment: @Bodo Yes, a python program with the same code works and I am able to connect to the database and retrieve data.

Comment: `cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples. I'm guessing the calling function is not prepared to deal with that kind of result.

Comment: @ArchitVerma Please [edit] your question and add all information there instead of answering in comments. Please show the working Python program and its output.

Comment: @tripleee I don't think that's the issue. I get the same error even if a try to return just one value from the list.

Answer (score 0):

your view (i.e. the `hello_world` function) needs to return something that's supported by Flask.  maybe have a look at the [Flask tutorial on Views](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/views/) to get more examples

the easiest would just be to convert this into a string and return that, e.g.:

```
import psycopg2

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    con = psycopg2.connect(db_conn_string)
    with con, con.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("SELECT * from xxx;")
        result = cur.fetchall()
    return repr(result)
```

I've rearranged your code to be a bit more conventional.  Note that `import`s normally go at the top.  you'd also want to make the connection string a constant at the top.  using `psycopg2` cursors as a context manager also wraps them in a transaction nicely, `COMMIT`ing on success and doing a `ROLLBACK` on exception

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sam! I have tried returning just ust one value from the list, that didn't help. I don't think the issue is that Flask is unable to understand the return statement.

Comment: what if you run flask outside of Apache?  i.e. just use [`flask run`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) as in the tutorial

Comment: It works fine. The code itself seems to have no problem. Somehow, when I run it on an apache server it gives me the segmentation fault error.

Comment: then maybe get apache to output more logging information to figure out where/what is actually failing.  maybe update the question to include relevant config settings